# Create a simple table with some annotations (Inkscape?)

Tags: inkscape, tables

I am completely new into this area. I want to draw some figures similar with this:
[image: asd]
For the tasks I am using Inkscape but I am open to suggestions if there is any other tool more suitable/user friendly.
Now, while i was trying to replicate the above figure, i hit a deadin from the first step:
Creating a table with NxM rows/columns

I have been searching for quite some time, I have found that is possible through Extensions->Render->Grid to draw some figures but I was not able to find how to create the table.

[Here](https://youtu.be/ySoTkwoXSd4?t=1489) he does something that could work, creates N*M boxes and rearranges them in order to create something similar to a table.

I was also trying to create the way it signifies the rows on the top left, i have managed to do it using calligraphic brush, but there is probably a more reliable/accurate way to do it right? (without depending on the user's ability to draw)

It can't be that hard, isn't it? Is Inkscape appropriate for my task and for amateurs?

Edit:
I have managed to create a table by first adding a rectangle with a stroke and then after selecting it->Path->Path Effects->Contruct Grid
This creates a grid but it doesn't allow a fine grained control over the lines, as for the example where the column separator is dashed. Either all lines are dashed or not.

Also for the selector, one can choose the bezier line, with some practice, you can achieve the line we see on the top left without much trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could certainly be done in Inkscape. It might not be the best software to make such grids however - perhaps it would be easier using spreadsheet software like Excel.

Anyhoo, in Inkscape:

1. Make one square with filled white, no stroke
2. Copy it and paste in place, stroke it black, no fill
3. Click `Path` > `Object to Path`
4. Using the `Edit Paths by Node` tool, select all the node points, and
   hit the `Break at Selected Nodes` icon in the options along the top
5. Break apart the shape using `Path` > `Break Apart`. This will
   allow you to select both the left and right side lines, and apply a
   dotted stroke.
6. To get the dots to match up the same on both sides, reverse the
   direction of one of the paths using `Path` > `Reverse`.
7. Select all, and group these elements together
   (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to group).

[image: example of square]

8. Enable snapping, and it's just a matter of copying and pasting each
   square to make a whole row, moving each square into position. With
   snapping enabled, Inkscape will show you when the squares are
   aligned

[image: example showing snapping]

9. When you have finished one full row of the table, use the `Edit paths by
   nodes` tool to select the end lines, and make them solid

[image]
 10. Select everything, and Group the whole row. Copy and paste, and
     move the row down until it aligns with snapping.

To apply a different coloured fill to some squares, select the inside white filled portion using the `Edit Paths by Nodes`and apply a different fill colour.

[image]

As for the the curly bracket, simply type <kbd>{</kbd> using the text tool, then select it and stretch/scale it, and apply a different fill colour.

Comment: If you want an example of the SVG, you can download it here: http://www.filedropper.com/table_2 - be quick, I have no idea how long this link will remain active.

Comment: Thanks  man, appreciate it. Just for future reference, which software would you suggest to use for that kind of draws?

Comment: Well, I'd use Inkscape, because I can.  However it might not suit everyone. There is a learning curve.  It's also fairly easy to create tables with coloured backgrounds and different line borders in Microsoft Excel, or virtually any spreadsheet software - even the free LibreOffice Calc - however these can't output vectors, so if you need vectors, go with Inkscape.

Comment: cheers man, very helpful